# Does power supply wastes power if connected to a laptop with an almost dead battery?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power-consumption

Does it keep chargin the battery all the time thus wasting power?

Comment: That would of course depend on how this “almost dead” state manifests. Does it appear fully charged?

Comment: @DanielB The battery only last for 40 minutes after being connected for a long time to the power supply. If the power supply has not been connected for hours it lasts just the time to boot into windows, so 2-3 minutes top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What **Daniel B** asks about is this: does the battery, after long charging, reports that is Fully charged (100%)? If Yes, then answer to the question is No.

Replace - or remove - the battery as it will negatively impact laptop performance (minimally) and remaining life time (possibly in major way), as system will try to charge it with full power, causing it to heat (which is actually normal in laptops), but since battery is faulty, the heat emitted from charged battery might be harmful to the system.

I recommend against removing the battery, as usually laptops are then imbalanced. It's better to just short it to at least have a bricked battery. I'd say it's much safer that way for all concerned.

EDIT:

You may have faulty battery, which is disabled by either it's IC, the charging circuit on laptop's motherboard or it's not charging because charging has been turned off (there is sometimes an option or a key combination - usually marked with an icon of a battery with a flash).
You need to check for all options and if charging is not turned off then it's the battery ("It's dead, Jim"). Either fork out on new one or try to find any just to test if that's the case...
Have a look in BIOS. Dell machines have quite often Battery status information in it. Don't really know about others, though, sorry.

Comment: Ok, I will leave it plugged in for a bit and see if it charges to 100%

Comment: I noticed that even if connected, Windows says that it's not in charge ("Connected, but not in charge").

Comment: @MarcoFilippozzi See edited answer, Please